# How do I change the color of text displayed in the Spring STS Roo Shell?

Tags: eclipse, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a requirement to use Spring STS with a black background and green text.

Unfortunately the color of text in the Roo Shell is a dark greeny/blue color, making it almost impossible for me to see against the black background.

Is there a way of changing the text color in the Roo Shell?

I've looked through the STS/Eclipse preferences and can't find anything. I really hope it hasn't been hard coded. If there's no setting in the STS Preferences, is there a property file somewhere where I can set it?

I am using STS Version: 2.6.1.RELEASE

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible yet to configure the background and text colors of the Roo Shell in SpringSource Tool Suite.

It has been added as a bug by a member of the SpringSource team to be fixed in STS v2.8.0.M1.
See - https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-1894

Comment: Has been implemented in current version 2.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use STS. You can just run it from the command line. I happen to have mine as green text with black background, because that is what my terminals display.

If that isn't helpful, what OS are you using?

I found that the colour of some window displays in Eclipse were controlled by the themes in my Ubuntu system. I just found the right one and changed the theme. (STS being based on Eclipse it may be the same)

Comment: I'm running STS on Windows XP SP3 - using a high contrast (green text on black background) display theme. I would prefer to run Roo inside Eclipse / STS if possible. Yes, the Windows command shell, although not ideal, is always a fall-back. But there must be a way to set the Roo Shell text color in STS / Eclipse.